# gnome-scheduler - 'command not found'

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scheduling, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu and I just switched my default terminal to gnome-terminal (I needed default login shell).

I noticed that gnome-scheduler is no longer lauching anything. For example, if I have a task that saying "ruby ~/test.rb" and I hit "run selected task", I get a window that states:

"/tmp/tmpBMBvq7: line 1: ruby: command not found"

This seems to be happening with any command. What is going on??

Comment: it seems that you've lost some part of your `$PATH` that contains ruby. Do you remember adding anything special to a dot-file to enable ruby before?

Comment: That's the weird part - all terminals anywhere else, whether it's a shortcut or the terminal keycommand, or I type "gnome-terminal", they all run ruby normally..

Comment: they're loading a file that updates $PATH that gnome-terminal is not -- I don't use gnome-terminal so I can't say for sure what that is.

Comment: I'm using RVM for ruby, which means I have to use a login shell. All other terminals work fine though... it's only the terminal that gets launched by gnome-scheduler that has an issue.. That's interesting about the $PATH variable getting updated. Does it only affect $PATH for that instance of terminal? How do I figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out RVM (which is how I'm using Ruby) has specific instructions for handling cron jobs.

In regards to my general cron issue, from researching, it seems .bashrc/.bash_profile/.profile aren't actually run by cron. This explains why ruby isn't found in $PATH.